# In Neutral Geometry, for every line L and point A, so A is not contained in L, there is a line L' which is parallel to L and A is contained in L'.

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry

this was a true/false question and I wrote false because it should be in Euclidean Geometry... but it is supposedly True. Can someone explain why? I thought when adding the parallel postulate to neutral geometry it changed to Euclidean. i.e. all Euclidean geometry is neutral, but not all neutral geometry is Euclidean

thanks

Comment: Existence of a parallel  can be proved in neutral geometry, whereas for unicity you need Euclid's fifth postulate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be proved without the use of the parallel postulate. If opposite angles are equal then the lines are parallel. The converse, that parallel lines make the same angle with a transversal, is the content of the parallel postulate. Playfairs postulate asserts that the line through A and parallel to L is unique. The latter does not hold in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: +1. I suppose you meant "alternate" angles rather than "opposite".